# Perl sort with regular expression

Tags: regex, perl, sorting

I have a perl array of strings like this:

```
my @arr = ( "gene1 (100)", "gene2 (50)", "gene3 (120)", ... );
```

How can I sort the array by the integer in parentheses?

Comment: Don't know enough Perl, but this is how you match the integer in parentheses: [`(?<=\()\d+(?=\))`](http://regex101.com/r/bO5mY2).  And here is some information for [sorting arrays in Perl](http://perlmaven.com/sorting-arrays-in-perl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shows the straightforward way. The `sort` block sets `$aa` and `$bb` to the values of the numbers in `$a` and `$b` respectively. Then `<=>` is used to compare them numerically.

There is no need for the much more obscure transformation method unless the basic technique proves to be too slow.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @arr = ( "gene1 (100)", "gene2 (50)", "gene3 (120)",  );

my @sorted = sort {
  my ($aa) = $a =~ / \(  (\d+)  \) /x;
  my ($bb) = $b =~ / \(  (\d+)  \) /x;
  $aa <=> $bb;
} @arr;

say for @sorted;
```

**output**

```
gene2 (50)
gene1 (100)
gene3 (120)
```

Comment: I tried to remember your preferred construct, but just went with an old faithful instead.  Next time.

Comment: @Miller: I would have used a `map` ordinarily, like so `my ($aa, $bb) = map { / \( (\d+) \) /x } $a, $b;` but it seemed best to stick with clarity

Answer (score 5):

Using a [transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) to compare the first number in the string

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr = ( "gene1 (100)", "gene2 (50)", "gene3 (120)");

my @sorted = map {$_->[0]}
             sort {$a->[1] <=> $b->[1]}
             map {[$_, /\b(\d+)\b/]} @arr;

print "$_\n" for @sorted;
```

Outputs:

```
gene2 (50)
gene1 (100)
gene3 (120)
```

Comment: This is faster than simbabque's solution if the regexp matching is slow, because it does only n regexp matches, and the other solution does between O(n*log(n)) and O(n^2). However, this solution uses more temporary memory.

Comment: I agree with @pts. Also, this solution requires a lot more explanation.

Comment: This is basically just the Schwartzian transformation; a variant of which is encapsulated by List::UtilsBy. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The [`sort` built-in](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) in Perl lets you pass a code reference as its first argument to define how the sort should be done. Inside this code ref, you can use any function you want.

Since you want to do it with a regular expression, it makes sense to create a `sub` that matches the numbers in the parenthesis and use that in your sorting function.

You need to call it once for `$a` and `$b`, the two variables that will be compared to each other for each round of sorting pairs. You should use the [`<=>` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators), which is used for sorting numbers in ascending order.

This is a very verbose version.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump;

my @arr = ( "gene1 (100)", "gene2 (50)", "gene3 (120)",  );

dd sort { get_number($a) <=> get_number($b) } @arr;

sub get_number {
  my ( $string ) = @_;
  return $1 if $string =~ m/\((\d+)\)/;   
  return 0; # assume it goes last if there is no number
}
```

Output:

```
("gene2 (50)", "gene1 (100)", "gene3 (120)")
```

Answer (score 1):

The `List::UtilsBy` CPAN module provides a function, `nsort_by` which sorts a list of values by sorting into numerical order, the values returned by a block of code on each value.

In your case, it can be used to extract that number:

```
use List::UtilsBy 'nsort_by';

@sorted = nsort_by { m/\((\d+)/ and $1 } @strings
```

This is somewhat more efficient than a regular `sort` call with code to extract and compare the two numbers from `$a` and `$b` directly, as it only has to extract the number from each value once, rather than once for every pair-wise comparison.